# Flutter: Disable application for tablet and ipad

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I'm developing an application on flutter and I want to disable the application for tablets on both android and ios.

Comment: You can follow the official documentation of android on Declare restricted screen support https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution#FilteringHandsetApps

Answer (score 9):

for android include these screen densities for your screen support between the manifest tags.

```
  <compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
 </compatible-screens>
```

for ios open the general settings from the runner and under deployment info uncheck the iPad support.

[image]

Comment: The part for Android was a bit suspicious where it comes from but the explanation can be found on https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element

Comment: what if i want to add iPad support after i publish my app with mobile support only? is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

For iOS there is Supported Destinations header in General tab of Runner settings

[image]